# Automate services restart in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-services, jboss, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I have a Jboss service in Windows server 2003. Is there a way to schedule the service to restart automatically on a daily basis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the following commands in a batch or cmd file and use windows scheduler to trigger it at desired schedule.

```
net stop <service_name>
net start <service_name>
```